# ListActivity not loading adapters style, loading white screen

Tags: java, android

I am working in android studio with GSON and Retrofit 1, which is stable. I am in need to find out why non of the information is showing, the GSON should be putting the JSON information in the model class of getters/setters. I am making a Movie App using the imdb api, I can share my code here if you would like to review the project as a whole, but otherwise below is some of the code:

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/EvanGlazer/Movie-Zone/tree/DetailController)

This is the detail item xml I am trying to populate then put in the list in the main xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.evanglazer.moviezone.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/top">

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/movieView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="IMDB Rating:"
        android:id="@+id/imdbText"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movieView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/movieView" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/imdbRatingText"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imdbText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imdbText"
        android:singleLine="true" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="UserBase Vote:"
        android:id="@+id/userText"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="@+id/imdbText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imdbText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/releaseDateText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/releaseDateText" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/userRatingText"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imdbText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imdbText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imdbText"
        android:singleLine="true" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Release Date:"
        android:id="@+id/releaseText"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/userRatingText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/userRatingText"
        />

     <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:id="@+id/releaseDateText"
     android:layout_below="@+id/releaseText"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/releaseText"
     android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/releaseText" />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/middle">

   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Trailer 1"
    android:id="@+id/trailer1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Trailer 2"
    android:id="@+id/trailer2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/trailer1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

   <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/trailer2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

Here is the detail main:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the detail activity:

```
public class DetailActivity extends ListActivity{

public static final String URL_IMAGE_ENDPOINT = "http://image.tmdb.org";
public static final String URL_API_ENDPOINT = "http://api.themoviedb.org";
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
List<MovieDetail> details;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_main);
    //fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main2, new Detail()).commit();
    //fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main2, new NavBar()).commit();

    if (isOnline()) {
        requestData();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

protected boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
private void requestData()
{
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL_API_ENDPOINT)
            .build();

    MovieAPI api = adapter.create(MovieAPI.class);

    api.getMovieDetails(new Callback<List<MovieDetail>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<MovieDetail> movieDetails, Response response) {
            details = movieDetails;
            // update display
            updateDisplay();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

protected void updateDisplay() {
    //Use FlowerAdapter to display data
    MovieDetailAdapter adapter = new MovieDetailAdapter(this,    R.layout.movie_detail_fragment, details);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 }
```

Here is how I am api through retrofit:

```
 public interface MovieAPI {

    @GET("/3/movie/273248?api_key=ea8f68dc2c7b43a3df248b9a638f5fb4")
    void getMovieDetails(Callback<List<MovieDetail>> callback);

    @GET("3/movie/5493/movie/549")
    void getPopularMovies(Callback<List<MovieDetail>> response);
    }
```

Here is the model for the objects I am trying to read in from the callback:

```
public class MovieDetail {

private String poster_path;
private String release_date;
private int id;
private String original_title;
private double vote_average;
private int gridPos;
private Bitmap bitmap;


public int getGridPos() {
    return gridPos;
}

public void setGridPos(int gridPos) {
    this.gridPos = gridPos;
}

public String getPoster_path() {
    return poster_path;
}

public void setPoster_path(String poster_path) {
    this.poster_path = poster_path;
}

public String getRelease_date() {
    return release_date;
}

public void setRelease_date(String release_date) {
    this.release_date = release_date;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getOriginal_title() {
    return original_title;
}

public void setOriginal_title(String original_title) {
    this.original_title = original_title;
}

public double getVote_average() {
    return vote_average;
}

public void setVote_average(double vote_average) {
    this.vote_average = vote_average;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
```